# Excel if or not returning expected result

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formula

My spreadsheet looks like this, where each cell contains a formula bringing the value from another sheet:

```
N         O   ...  R     S     T      U
Process   Loc      U1    U2    U3     IsValid
Bestly    20       8     20    20     Invalid
```

Where the formula in U:

```
=IF(OR(O51=R51,O51=S51,O51=T51),"Valid","Invalid")
```

It should have returned Valid, since 20 is in both columns S and T.  Is there something wrong with the formula that I need to fix to get it to return Valid when it finds the value in O in at least one column?

Thanks! This is Excel in Office 16.

Comment: Looks valid to me. Are you sure these are all numeric values without funny characters? Another way would be to use `=IF(COUNTIF(R51:T51,O51),"valid","invalid")`

Comment: Could it be that the calculated values are actual 20 or for instance 20,0001 showing as 20?

Comment: It's a vlookup of an actual 20 in another sheet

Comment: @JvdV Your idea with Countif worked! It's showing valid where it should now! Good idea.

Comment: @Michele, I'll make it an answer for closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my comment:

Looks valid to me. Are you sure these are all numeric values without funny characters? Another way would be to use:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(R51:T51,O51),"valid","invalid")
```